# Why don't i have to overload the assignment operator in c++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Here is my code:

```
class Example {
 ...declarations/definitions...
};

Example operator + (Example e)
{
 Example temp;
 ...do addition...
 return temp;
}

//main
void main()
{
 Example a(1,2);
 Example b(3,4);
 Example c;
 c = a+b;
}
```

Now what confuses me is that I had to overload the + operator for it to work with the vectors but how about the equal '=' sign?? I am assigning one vector to another, shouldn't i be overloading it too?? Or is it provided already to us?
Thanks.

Comment: That definition looks like a unary `+` operator, not an addition.

Comment: @Azza, close, but not quite.  It assigns each of the members, but not bitwise.  Also the compiler makes default constructors, destructors, move constructors, and move assignment operators automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The language provides a default `operator=` for you automatically if your class is default assignable (for example if it has any reference members it won't be assignable without special work by you). All it does is assign the base and each member individually.

Answer (score 3):

From the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_operator_%28C%2B%2B%29):

> The default version [of the assignment operator] performs a memberwise copy, where each member is copied by its own copy assignment operator (which may also be programmer-declared or compiler-generated).

Comment: English? I know what you're saying, but others might not.

Comment: @ThatOtherPerson that's English if I ever saw any.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't declare a copy-assignment operator in your class, then one is implicitly declared for you (and implicitly defined if you ever use it).

The implicit operator will assign each member of your object, if that's possible; otherwise (if some member is a reference, or `const`, or has a private or deleted copy-assignment operator) you'll get a compile error.

Similarly, if you don't declare a copy constructor, then you'll get an implicit one, which will copy each member. Your code is using that in `operator+`, to copy both the argument and the return value.

Answer (score 1):

The assignment operator is given by default, along with the copy constructor, and default constructor. It assigns the value of each data member to its corresponding data member in the other object (i.e., shallow copy).

Answer (score 0):

A `std::vector`? If so, `std::vector` implements the assignment operator by default.  From the manpage:

"Assigns a copy of vector x as the new content for the vector object.

The elements contained in the vector object before the call are dropped, and replaced by copies of those in vector x, if any.

After a call to this member function, both the vector object and vector x will have the same size and compare equal to each other."

edit-one of these days I'm going to submit an answer first!

Answer (score 0):

C++ provides a [default copy constructor for you that is used for assignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_operator_(C%2B%2B)), it copies the class member by member using their (also possibly default) copy constructors.